# Docker Macvlan network inside container is not reaching to its own host

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, macvlan

I have setup Macvlan network between 2 docker host as follows:

#### Host Setup: HOST_1 `ens192: 172.18.0.21`

Create macvlan bridge interface

```
docker network  create  -d macvlan \
--subnet=172.18.0.0/22 \
--gateway=172.18.0.1 \
--ip-range=172.18.1.0/28 \
-o macvlan_mode=bridge \
-o parent=ens192 macvlan
```

Create macvlan interface HOST_1

```
ip link add ens192.br link ens192 type macvlan mode bridge
ip addr add 172.18.1.0/28 dev ens192.br
ip link set dev ens192.br up
```

#### Host Setup: HOST_2 `ens192: 172.18.0.23`

Create macvlan bridge interface

```
docker network  create  -d macvlan \
--subnet=172.18.0.0/22 \
--gateway=172.18.0.1 \
--ip-range=172.18.1.16/28 \
-o macvlan_mode=bridge \
-o parent=ens192 macvlan
```

Create macvlan interface in HOST_2

```
ip link add ens192.br link ens192 type macvlan mode bridge
ip addr add 172.18.1.16/28 dev ens192.br
ip link set dev ens192.br up
```

#### Container Setup

Create containers in both host

```
HOST_1# docker run --net=macvlan -it --name macvlan_1 --rm alpine /bin/sh
HOST_2# docker run --net=macvlan -it --name macvlan_1 --rm alpine /bin/sh
```

CONTAINER_1 in HOST_1

```
24: eth0@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/ether 02:42:ac:12:01:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.1.0/22 brd 172.18.3.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

CONTAINER_2 in HOST_2

```
21: eth0@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/ether 02:42:ac:12:01:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.1.16/22 brd 172.18.3.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Route table in CONTAINER_1 and CONTAINER_2

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.18.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

#### Scenario

`HOST_1 (172.18.0.21) <-> HOST_2 (172.18.0.23)` = OK (Vice-versa)

`HOST_1 (172.18.0.21) -> CONTAINER_1 (172.18.1.0) and CONTAINER_2 (172.18.1.16)` = OK

`HOST_2 (172.18.0.23) -> CONTAINER_1 (172.18.1.0) and CONTAINER_2 (172.18.1.16)` = OK

`CONTAINER_1 (172.18.1.0) -> HOST_2 (172.18.0.23)` = OK

`CONTAINER_2 (172.18.1.16) -> HOST_1 (172.18.0.21)` = OK

`CONTAINER_1 (172.18.1.0) <-> CONTAINER_2 (172.18.1.16)` = OK (Vice-versa)

`CONTAINER_1 (172.18.1.0) -> HOST_1 (172.18.0.21)` = FAIL

`CONTAINER_2 (172.18.1.16) -> HOST_2 (172.18.0.23)` = FAIL

#### Question

I am very close to my solution I wanted to achieve except this 1 single problem.  How can I make this work for container to connect to its own host.  If there is solution to this, I would like to know how to configure in ESXi virtualization perspective and also bare-metal if there is any difference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is defined behavior for macvlan and is by design. See [Docker Macvlan Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-macvlan/)

> - When using macvlan, you cannot ping or communicate with the default namespace IP address. For example, if you create a container and try to ping the Docker host’s eth0, it will not work. That traffic is explicitly filtered by the kernel modules themselves to offer additional provider isolation and security.
> - A macvlan subinterface can be added to the Docker host, to allow traffic between the Docker host and containers. The IP address needs to be set on this subinterface and removed from the parent address.

Comment: Note that current (2020-06) documentation no longer says this.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why this information was removed from the documentation because from what I can tell, the same limitation is still in place. But I'm also finding indications that there are workarounds that actually do allow for host-container communication, e.g. as described in [this blog post](https://sreeninet.wordpress.com/2016/05/29/docker-macvlan-and-ipvlan-network-plugins/).

Answer (score 16):

The question is "a bit old", however others might find it useful.  There is a workaround described in ***Host access*** section of [USING DOCKER MACVLAN NETWORKS BY LARS KELLOGG-STEDMAN](https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2018-03-12-using-docker-macvlan-networks/). I can confirm - it's working.

> Host access With a container attached to a macvlan network, you will
> find that while it can contact other systems on your local network
> without a problem, the container will not be able to connect to your
> host (and your host will not be able to connect to your container).
> This is a limitation of macvlan interfaces: without special support
> from a network switch, your host is unable to send packets to its own
> macvlan interfaces.
>
> Fortunately, there is a workaround for this problem: you can create
> another macvlan interface on your host, and use that to communicate
> with containers on the macvlan network.
>
> First, I’m going to reserve an address from our network range for use
> by the host interface by using the --aux-address option to docker
> network create. That makes our final command line look like:
>
> ```
> docker network create -d macvlan -o parent=eno1 \
>   --subnet 192.168.1.0/24 \
>   --gateway 192.168.1.1 \
>   --ip-range 192.168.1.192/27 \
>   --aux-address 'host=192.168.1.223' \
>   mynet
> ```
>
> This will prevent Docker from assigning that address to a container.
>
> Next, we create a new macvlan interface on the host. You can call it
> whatever you want, but I’m calling this one mynet-shim:
>
> ```
> ip link add mynet-shim link eno1 type macvlan  mode bridge
> ```
>
> Now we need to configure the interface with the address we reserved
> and bring it up:
>
> ```
> ip addr add 192.168.1.223/32 dev mynet-shim
> ip link set mynet-shim up
> ```
>
> The last thing we need to do is to tell our host to use that interface
> when communicating with the containers. This is relatively easy
> because we have restricted our containers to a particular CIDR subset
> of the local network; we just add a route to that range like this:
>
> ```
> ip route add 192.168.1.192/27 dev mynet-shim
> ```
>
> With that route in place, your host will automatically use ths
> mynet-shim interface when communicating with containers on the mynet
> network.
>
> Note that the interface and routing configuration presented here is
> not persistent – you will lose if if you were to reboot your host. How
> to make it persistent is distribution dependent.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for the answer and the effort on copying it here! I hope it can help people with the same issue.

Comment: It's totally save my day, good job! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and I found the network config would gone after reboot, So it's better to use `nmcli` to create macvlan connection.
`nmcli connection add type macvlan mode bridge ipv4.address 192.168.31.51/24 ipv4.gateway 192.168.31.188 ipv4.dns 192.168.31.188 connection.autoconnect true ipv4.method static dev eno1`

Comment: Thank you so much. That really makes sense!

Answer (score 5):

In my situation, I added one more network to the container.

so `CONTAINER_1 -> HOST_1` can be reached by a different IP (`10.123.0.2`).

`CONTAINER_2` or `HOST_2` can reach to `172.18.1.0`.

Following is the `docker-compose` sample, hope this could be a workaround.

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  macvlan_1:
    image: alpine
    container: macvlan_1
    command: ....
    restart: always
    networks:
      macvlan:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.1.0
      internalbr:
        ipv4_address: 10.123.0.2

networks:
  macvlan:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: ens192
      macvlan_mode: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.18.0.0/22
          gateway: 172.18.0.1
          ip_range: 172.18.1.0/28

  internalbr:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.123.0.0/24
```