# How do I enable Nginx Proxy Manager on a macvlan Docker network to successfully redirect to Synology DSM on the host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, synology

I'm running the full htpc suite (Sonarr / Radarr / Plex etc) on a Synology NAS, with [Nginx Proxy Manager](https://github.com/jc21/nginx-proxy-manager) successfully redirecting from personal sub-domains to containerised services, e.g.:

- `plex.domain.com` -> Plex @ `192.168.0.10`
- `ombi.domain.com` -> Ombi @ `192.168.0.11`

All of my containers are defined in docker-compose, using `macvlan` in order to have an IP per service. This works great on all fronts (about 15  different services), with the exception of connecting to the NAS admin itself. After defining an Nginx Proxy Manager proxy-host to redirect to the NAS admin, any request is always met with a `502`, served by Nginx Proxy Manager.

Example docker-compose network and service definitions are as follows (Docker version 18.09.0-0519):

```
...

networks:
  internal_net:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: ovs_eth0
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.0.0/24

nginx-proxy-manager:
  image: jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest
  hostname: nginx-proxy-manager
  domainname: domain.com
  networks:
    internal_net:
      ipv4_address: 192.168.0.50
  ...

plex:
  image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/plex
  hostname: plex
  domainname: domain.com
  networks:
    trackness_net:
      ipv4_address: 192.168.0.10
  ...
```

With the Nginx Proxy Manager proxy-host pointing `dsm.domain.com` to `192.168.0.<nas-ip>:5000` (and having tried `80`, `443`, and `5001` out of desperation), the result is always the same: `502`.

From what I've been able to determine, this is due to a macvlan network being unable to connect to the host, which leaves me in a pickle. I can't imagine I'm the only person to ever shoot for this setup or one similar; can anyone help? How do I enable Nginx Proxy Manager on `macvlan` to communicate with `192.168.0.<nas-ip>:5000`?

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is now 9 months old, but I ran into the exact same problem today. After some trial and error and searching the web I found this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67835834

After connecting the nginx-container to the two networks, I simply put the assigned bridge-network-host-ip (in this case 10.123.0.1) as the backend target and it works flawlessly.

I hope you already found a solution or that this helps.
Cheers